# Using findBySQL with sum function in yii2 sql query not working

Tags: yii2

I am using the following query to get the sum of values but getting errors in yii2.

```
$sql = 'SELECT sum(bid_item.$quantity), bid_item.product_id FROM
bid_item WHERE bid_item.product_price >=710 AND bid_item.product_id=2
GROUP BY bid_item.product_id'; 
$bidItem = BidItem::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
$command = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT sum(bid_item.$quantity), bid_item.product_id FROM bid_item WHERE bid_item.product_price >=710 AND bid_item.product_id=2 GROUP BY bid_item.product_id");
$result= $command->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is OK to use your code, but you must change it like that:

```php
$sql = 'SELECT sum(bid_item.$quantity) AS sum, bid_item.* '
    .'FROM bid_item '
    .'WHERE bid_item.product_price >=710 AND bid_item.product_id=2 '
    .'GROUP BY bid_item.product_id';
$bidItem = BidItem::findBySql($sql)->all();
```

And have a `sum` property in the model class `BidItem`.

```php
class BidItem extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $sum;

    ... all other declarations of the model
}
```

`bid_item.*` is required to initialize all other attributes of the `BidItem` model, while `sum(bid_item.$quantity) AS sum` is a normal way to declare a calculatable attribute as [noted in doc](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#selecting-extra-fields).